# undefined method `create' for Tempfile:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nomethoderror, ruby-2.1

I have a problem with Tempfile class.

```
elem = Tempfile.create(["path_to_file", ".pdf"], Rails.root.join('tmp'))
```

This code sample is working on my development ENV, but not in testing nor production ENV.

Error:

```
undefined method `create' for Tempfile:Class
```

Does someone know what is going on?

Only think Mr. Google found is some bug linked with a kitchen-docker.

Both, development and testing ENV are using

> ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
>
> Rails 3.2.13

The only difference is the testing ENV is running on a nginx

I can even see in a /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb a method Tempfile.create

Thanks for any suggestions

**edit**: it came to light a ruby version on testing ENV is actually 2.0.0 and i have a messed up ruby versions because of RVM, thanks everyone for effort

Comment: Standard ruby [`Tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) does not have `create` method (it has `new`.) I would suggest you to use [`rvm`](http://rvm.io) to manage ruby versions to clearly understand what ruby with what gemset is executed.

Comment: @mudasobwa as of [`>= 2.1`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-create) it does. It actually creates a `File` rather than a `Tempfile`. I think you are on the right track about his ruby versions being off. I also agree `new` would probably be sufficient as the whole concept of `Tempfile.create` seems misleading to me.

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh, good to know, thanks.

Comment: Simple debugging and sanity check: add `raise ENV['RUBY_VERSION']` just above problematic line and see what you'll get.

Comment: Thanks @BroiSatse, came to light a ruby version on testing ENV is actually 2.0.0 and i have a messed up ruby versions because of RVM